# RED LANGUAGE : changing button image doesn't work

Tags: red

I tried to do this, but after clicking nothing happens:

```
view [
    button %head.jpg [
        face/image: %tail.jpg
    ]
]
```

Update: RED IS A LANGUAGE I PRECISE SINCE ASKED :)

Comment: It's in TITLE and tag didn't you see ? RED language http://red-lang.org

Comment: @lurker is it you who flagged for close ?!

Comment: "Red" is a pretty generic term and I didn't recognize it as a language. Thanks for updating to be specific.

Comment: Works with `base` (and probably more) instead of `button`.

Comment: Image support in the `button` style is preliminary (they are native widgets and require extra support for this). Please submit a ticket at https://github.com/red/red/issues for this, and work around it using the `base` style for now.

Comment: Ahem, I already filled the ticket for you after asking on Reds gitter. Here it is: https://github.com/red/red/issues/3776. If you have further useful information, feel free to comment.